Generic hyperplane sections of an irreducible projective variety is irreducible
I am reading Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris. They asserted that the generic hyperplane section $H\cap V$ of an irreducible nondegenerate variety $V$ of dimension $\geq 2$ is again irreducible.
The proof follows: pick a smooth point $p\in V$ and choose a plane $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$ meeting $V$ transversely at $p$. Consider the pencil $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\lambda}$ of hyperplanes $H_{\lambda}$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ containing $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$. Then, for each hyperplane section $H_{\lambda}\cap V$, we choose the unique irreducible component $V_{\lambda}$ containing $p$. Let $V'=\cup_{\lambda}V_{\lambda}$. They claimed that 
1.$V'$ is an open subvariety of V, and the closure of $V'$ must be V.
2.Then is follows that for generic $\lambda$, $H_{\lambda}\cap V=H_{\lambda}\cap V'$.
I could only see that $V'$ is an open subset of $V$; hence, it is an open subvariety. This is because the pencil sweeps out the whole $\mathbb{P}^{n}$. But where do the above two conclusions come from? An open subvariety can not guarantee its closure to be all of $V$. Indeed, the closure per se is not guaranteed to be a variety. I hope that anyone can give me an elementary explanation of it.
